# Logstash | ConfigurationError :message=>Expected one of [ \\t\\r\\n], \"#\", \"input\", \"filter\", \"output\" at line 1, column 1 (byte 1)

Tags: configuration, logstash, elastic-stack, elk

I am getting config error while launching Logstash. I am using 7.5.1 version.
Same config file worked earlier. I had to setup ELK stash on another VM since older VM was decommissioned, and I am facing this error here.

**I'm instantiating logstash using -**

> logstash-7.5.1\bin\logstash -f logstash-config.conf

.

**Config File -**

```
#config file

input{
jdbc{
jdbc_driver_library=>"C:\software\ojdbc7.jar"
jdbc_driver_class=>"Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
jdbc_connection_string=>"jdbc:oracle:thin:@<host>:1528:TSTIM"
jdbc_user=>"UName"
jdbc_password=>"PWD"
statement=>"SELECT * from TABLE where run_id > 4500"
}
}

output{
elasticsearch{
hosts=>"http://localhost:9200"
index=>"run_id"
document_type=>"TABLEname"
document_id=>"run_id"
user=>"elastic"
password=>"changeme"
}
stdout{
codec=>rubydebug
}
}
```

.

**Error -**

```
C:\software>logstash-7.5.1\bin\logstash -f logstash-config.conf
Thread.exclusive is deprecated, use Thread::Mutex
Sending Logstash logs to C:/software/logstash-7.5.1/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2020-01-08T05:04:33,207][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2020-01-08T05:04:33,426][INFO ][logstash.runner ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.5.1"}
[2020-01-08T05:04:34,869][ERROR][logstash.agent ] Failed to execute action 
{:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main,
:exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError",
:message=>"Expected one of [ \t\r\n], "#", "input", "filter", "output" at line 1, column 1 (byte 1)", 
:backtrace=>[
"C:/software/logstash-7.5.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:41:in compile_imperative'",
"C:/software/logstash-7.5.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:49:in compile_graph'",
"C:/software/logstash-7.5.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:11:in block in compile_sources'",
"org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2584:in map'",
"C:/software/logstash-7.5.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:10:in compile_sources'", 
"org/logstash/execution/AbstractPipelineExt.java:156:in initialize'",
"org/logstash/execution/JavaBasePipelineExt.java:47:in initialize'", 
"C:/software/logstash-7.5.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:27:in initialize'", 
"C:/software/logstash-7.5.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:36:in execute'", 
"C:/software/logstash-7.5.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:326:in block in converge_state'"
]}
[2020-01-08T05:04:35,510][INFO ][logstash.agent ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2020-01-08T05:04:40,325][INFO ][logstash.runner ] Logstash shut down.
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bad. The config file had some bad characters. I just had to cleanup.
Hand typing the same config content onto another file worked.

Comment: which bad characters? I'm kinda stuck with this issue myself.

Comment: Typing the contents from the scratch worked for me on Windows machine.
You can use sed or dos2unix commands to clean the file using a unix system and then place it.

Comment: thanks. my issue was slightly different. I'm on linux only, so the dos2unix thing wouldn't help. Turns out you can't have comments in a YAML file. Dumb me. The message is rather cryptic still.

Comment: I had to change line endings from CRLF -> LF

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue on Windows using Notepad++.

My solution is to save config into `UTF-8 without BOM` and `Unix format (LF)`.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, when copy/paste some strings in my config file from web page.
The reason is that there are non-printable characters other than "tab" or "whitespace" at the beginning of the line. You can see the difference between good and bad lines if you select the entire contents of the file in VS Code.

I replaced bad characters to spaces and the problem was solved.